# What causes the InvalidComObjectException: "COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used."?

Tags: winforms, interop, activex, dispose, finalizer

I've looked at the various questions that mention this specific exception ([this question lists many of them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109065/invalidcomobjectexception-com-object-that-has-been-separated-from-its-underlying), which I've visited). Also, I have the same [general question as this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492879/com-object-that-has-been-separated-from-its-underlying-rcw-can-not-be-used-why), but in a different context, so [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492879/com-object-that-has-been-separated-from-its-underlying-rcw-can-not-be-used-why/2237800#2237800) is not helpful to me.

**The context**

I have a class derived from [`AxWindowsMediaPlayer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd562388%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that is owned by a class called `View`, which is within a `Panel`, within a `Workspace`. I recently asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5279448/objects-need-to-be-disposed-in-a-specific-order-is-this-a-code-smell) around this situation, but that question was directed towards whether my workaround for *this* problem is okay. The background from that question is relevant here:

```
    .-----------------------.
    |Workspace              |
    |.--------.  .--------. |
    ||Panel1  |  |Panel2  | |
    ||.-----. |  |.-----. | |
    |||View1| |  ||View2| | |
    ||'-----' |  |'-----' | |
    |'--------'  '--------' |
    '-----------------------'
```

When a `View` gets disposed, a method called `Synchronize()` will get called on all of the remaining `View` objects. For the `View` that contains the `AxWindowsMediaPlayer`, it calls [`videoPlayer.Error.clearErrorQueue()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd562905%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

**The problem**

When I call `Dispose()` at the top level (`Workspace.Dispose()`), if another `View` gets disposed and then causes `Synchronize()` to be called on the remaining `View` objects, the `View` containing the `AxWindowsMediaPlayer` class throws an exception on the `videoPlayer.Error.clearErrorQueue()` line, stating:

> InvalidComObjectException: COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used.

I'm puzzled by how the `AxWindowsMediaPlayer` is getting separated from its underlying RCW ([Runtime Callable Wrapper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bwh56xe.aspx)). I've read [this article that talks about this exception](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/03/01/marshal-releasecomobject-considered-dangerous.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0) and the dangers of calling [`Marshal.ReleaseComObject()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.releasecomobject.aspx). I am not calling this method explicitly. I have put breakpoints at the `Dispose` methods of `Panel` and `View` and `VideoPlayerControl` (derives from `AxWindowsMediaPlayer`) classes, but none of those get hit before the exception happens.

My workaround is to make sure that the `View` with the media player always gets disposed first. This was the motivation behind my previous question. But I'd like to understand how this is happening so I can see whether this is something I need to fix. **Who is causing the `AxWindowsMediaPlayer` to be separated from its RCW before `Dispose` is getting called on the parent class?**

My guess is that the `AxWindowsMediaPlayer` finalizer is getting called by the GC, but I don't understand what is triggering it. For some reason, calling `Dispose` at the higher level is causing `Marshal.ReleaseComObject` to get called under the floor. Can someone enlighten me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your workaround is, unfortunately, the solution.

`Control.Dispose` recursively disposes all ActiveX controls first, and it then recursively calls `Dispose` on child controls.  In your example, if you call `Workspace.Dispose`, your `AxWindowsMediaPlayer` will be disposed first, then `Panel1`, `Panel2`, `View1`, `View2` (depending on the order you built up your control tree).

We can discover the cause by using [Reflector](http://www.reflector.net/).  If we examine `Control.Dispose`, it is essentially implemented as follows (note, irrelevant code omitted and slightly changed to improve readability):

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing)
    {
        DisposeAxControls();

        foreach (Control control in Controls)
        {
            control.Parent = null;
            control.Dispose();
        }

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

And `DisposeAxControls` is implemented as:

```
internal virtual void DisposeAxControls()
{
    foreach (Control control in Controls)
    {
        control.DisposeAxControls();
    }
}
```

The `AxHost` class overrides `DisposeAxControls` to destroy the hosted ActiveX control.

I'm not really sure why the `DisposeAxControls` function exists.  It seems that `AxHost` would have simply overridden `Dispose`, like everyone else, to destroy the ActiveX control, but that's not how things are implemented.